# How to specify the conversion format of a date to a string

Tags: iphone, ios, date, uidatepicker

I am creating an app where the current date needs to be displayed in a label and automatically updated each day. I have looked at a few tutorials and they have all shown how to get the date in YYYY:DD:MM hh:mm, I am wondering how to change this format to DD/MMM/YYYY.

Any sample code or links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
NSDate          *today     = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateformatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"];
[myLabel   setText:[formatter stringFromDate:today]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dayDate];

//display dateString in label

[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the NSDateFormatter. For specfic formats look at 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];
```

Comment: @Inafziger According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a quick test, now does contain the current date and time.